# Error on taking screenshot in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take screenshot in Selenium C# with a simple code below

```
public void takeScreenshot()
    {
        Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)DriverContext.Driver).GetScreenshot();
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"C:\images\image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

As soon as I call this method in me test code, it throws the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-
extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
(Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 
(e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

I researched quite a bit and found that

1. this might be due to old chrome driver version for which I installed the latest one but it still gives the error
2. The website might not be navigating to www for which I checked by navigating to www.google.com, but it still does not work.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: add the code in which you load the extension. Add the version of your used libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in my TearDown and it's working for me - maybe something with what DriverContext.Driver is resolving to at that point?

```
[TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
        {
            var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)browser).GetScreenshot();
            var filename = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName + "_screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg";
            var path = "C:\\Temp\\" + filename;
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(path , ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
            TestContext.AddTestAttachment(path);
        }
        browser.Quit();
    }
```